# Strange POST request to server in apache log

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, php, http

I have been seeing this all day in my apache access log:

```
213.55.105.126 - - [19/Jul/2014:18:39:24 +0000] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.1" 503 2539 "-" "-"
```

they are continuously coming in. different IP address on every request. Probably about 1 or 2 a second ... really putting a load on my server.

By the way, I am hosting a few Wordpress sites on this server...

Does anyone know what this file does, and how to prevent it from being posted to my server? I can't block an IP, so I'm wondering if there is a way to block this from my server.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you disable it in your WordPress configuration?

Comment: Yes, I went through and disabled it on all my wordpress sites, and I'm still seeing this post request coming in.

Comment: Well, [they can still _try_ but...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rYr7I4gOSXk)

Comment: Yeah I know, I just really don't want my server to be bogged down because of this

Comment: If it _isn't_ bogging down your server, don't worry about it. They'll eventually figure it out and go away. If it _is_, then try something like Bad Behavior (disclaimer: I wrote it).

Comment: This is the only thing that I see in my access logs though. xmlrpc over and over, and my server load avg is never this high. so it is indeed slowing my server down.

Comment: [This exploit](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/4137) is the reason - hackers saw that you have WordPress, and are trying to use it as a zombie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Files xmlrpc.php>
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

Adding this to all .htaccess for all my sites seemed to fix... 
still getting lines in my apache access log, but my server load avg is back to normal.

Comment: You can also whitelist domains using "Allow from x.x.x"